# Feature scaling difference between "normalize" and "Normalizer"

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-science, feature-extraction, unsupervised-learning

can someone help me with the difference in feature scaling using normalize vs normalizer as in

- preprocessing.normalize() vs preprocessing.Normalizer() .

Answer (score 2):

They are equivalent in terms of their effect on the data.  The `normalize` function is intended to be a 'quick and easy' option to normalise a single vector/matrix.  `Normalizer` is what's known as a 'utility class'.  It just wraps the `normalize` function in Sklearn's `Transformer` API.  As stated in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#preprocessing-normalization), this makes the `Normalizer` class well-suited for use in Sklearn's [`Pipeline` class](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline).

** **Update to provide more details** **

***Normalisers***

The functionality of `normalize` and `Normalizer` is identical.  I.e. given the same data and parameters they will each return the L1 or L2 norm of the input matrix.

See the `sklearn.preprocessing.normalizer` [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html#sklearn.preprocessing.normalize) for more details.

***Transformers***

`Normalizer` is an example of a *transformer*.  Transformers can process data in a wide variety of ways.  One thing they all have in common in sklearn is having `fit`, `transform` and `fit_transform` methods.

See the data transformer [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/data_transforms.html) for more details.

***Pipelines***

`sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline` is a class for 'chaining' data transformations (normalisation, scaling, filtering etc.) and an estimator.  Being able to do this is helpful when using cross-validation to optimise different parameters in the preprocessing transformations and the estimator.

Because of the way `sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline` works, it requires constituent functions to use the `transformer` API.  I.e to have `fit`, `transform` and `fit_transform` methods.

See the `sklearn.pipeline.Pipline` [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline) for more details.

***Difference Between `Normalize` and `Normalizer`***

`Normalize` does not have `fit`, `transform` and `fit_transform` methods.  So whilst it is suited to 'standalone' use, it can't be used as part of a `Pipeline`.  `Normalizer` is wrapped in sklearn's `Transformer` API in order to provide the `Transformer` methods.

Therefore `Normalizer` allows the `normalize` function to be used with the `fit`, `transform` and `fit_transform` methods, which in turn allows it to be used as part of a `Pipeline`.

***Notes***

1. Because there is no model to fit when normalising data (technically because, `normalize` is *stateless* apart from the configuration parameters, e.g. which axis to normalise on and which type of normalisation to use) it only needs the `transform` method.  So `fit` returns the input without modification and `fit_transform` behaves the same as `transform`.
2. There may be other reasons for having the `Transformer` API available to `normalize` but its use as part of a `Pipeline` is the most common.

Comment: I have same question , I am new to Maachine Learning . But whatever difference you explained , I am not able to understand .Can you give some example and explain in littel more details

Comment: @user8588795 I've updated the answer, hopefully that allows you to understand – let me know if not.  Sorry for the delay in providing the update, I hope it didn't hinder you.